# How can I ensure screen reader accessibility for text input fields that mimic password fields without triggering the 'save password' pop-up?

Tags: security, firefox, input, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm facing an issue regarding OTP and OTP Security Question password input fields that triggers the 'save password' popup while also considering screen reader accessibility.

Initially, I addressed the popup problem by using an input element with **type="text"** and applying the **text-security** font-family (from https://github.com/noppa/text-security), following the guidance from this article: https://medium.com/@idanhareven/how-to-workaround-browsers-save-password-password-autocomplete-features-135b91ad06d2. I made necessary customizations to ensure compatibility across various browsers.

While I successfully achieved a solution that works across browsers, a new challenge emerged. When a screen reader interacts with the content and focuses on the input field, it reads out each entered character individually due to the type="text" attribute. If I change the input type to type="password", the screen reader doesn't provide any feedback on the user's input, but the popup appears on some browsers.

My goal is to find a solution that prevents the 'save password' popup from appearing after submission, while ensuring that the screen reader treats the input as a password field and doesn't audibly reveal each character entered.

I attempted to address the issue by initially setting the input field as type="password", and then dynamically changing it to type="text" during the onsubmit method. However, this approach is ineffective on Firefox, as it still triggers the "save password" pop-up. It seems like if i have a input of type="password" at any time, the browser will detect, remember and show the popup, which I don't want to.

Here is a basic code snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-save-as-password-popup-from-showing-on-all-browsers-hdzygm?file=/index.html

**My objectives are twofold:

1. Prevent the appearance of the "save password" pop-up on all browsers.
2. Ensure that screen readers do not audibly disclose the password (the entered input) to users.**

Do you have any insights or suggestions on how I can successfully achieve both of these goals?

Comment: I would be interested to know why that "save password" is a problem for you who provide whatever service to your customers ? Trying such hacks is never good as it can stop working tomorrow without talking about accessibility. Users should be able to decide for themselves at home or on their own machine, and it should be a system policy when users are at work or using computers provided by their company.